# PHP file permission errors

Tags: php, linux, apache

I have a folder which php uploads to located in the directory above www (/home/user/upload). I have made the folders permissions 770 and made a custom group, which includes user apache and nobody, to own it.

When I do a chgrp mygrp upload, php is able to upload to it, but after it does one time... it all of a sudden can't write or read from it anymore...

Anyone have any ideas?

**====EDIT====**

Here is the code I'm currently using to dl a remote file:

```
$ch = curl_init($url);

$image = TMP_DIR.'/'.getRandomString(10).".{$info->extension}";
while (file_exists($image))
    $image = TMP_DIR.'/'.getRandomString(10).".{$info->extension}";

$image_handle = fopen($image, 'w');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $image_handle);
if (curl_exec($ch) === false)
    throw new Exception('Curl error: '.curl_error($ch), curl_errno($ch));

curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: May we see what code you're using please?

Comment: What does getRandomString look like?  Does the code above throw an exception?

Comment: @Obto - What error do you get, if any, when the write fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well i feel a bit stupid now... after adding and changing users and groups I never restarted php or apache. So if anyone else ever has this problem make sure you do that first.

Thanks for your time and help guys!